# Config SSL RestTemplate with JKS without use httpClient in spring boot

Tags: web-services, rest, ssl-certificate, resttemplate, jks

I want config SSL with `restTemplate` but all the examples that we are searched, use `httpClient`. Now i want config **without** httpClient.